# Export Default Date for Certain Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use generate scripts menu to export insert scripts from SQL Server.
The database contains `LastModified` `datetime` column in each table.

For control data `LastMofified` is not critical data. I need to edit generated scripts everytime manually to replace with `GETDATE()` function.

I believe there has to be a better way. How do expert DBAs handler this scenario?

Comment: How about using the script as is, then following it up with an UPDATE [table] SET LastModified = GETDATE()

Comment: @Matt Yep that would be a neat alternative solution, if I can't generate the insert scripts with function name. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE ACTIVITY 
(ActivityId INT,
Name VARCHAR(10),
LastModifiedByUserId INT,
LastModifiedDate DATETIME )


DECLARE @Date DATETIME = GETDATE()
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Activity] ON 
    INSERT INTO [Activity] ([ActivityId],[Name],[Description],[LastModifiedByUserId],[LastModifiedDate])VALUES(1,'Raj',1,@Date)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Activity] OFF
```